# StringJoin with Spaces

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I'm having some trouble using StringJoin --- the problem is that the StringJoin function creates a string where all the words in a list are combined without any spaces (whitespace)

For instance,
list = {"hi","how","are","you"}
StringJoin[list] will give me hihowareyou
What do I have to do to get hi how are you as one string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use `ListFormat`

```
  TextString[list, ListFormat -> {"", "    ", ""}]
```

gives

```
   "hi    how    are    you"
```

Comment: Thank you for this! All of the answers here worked but I found this to be the simplest

Answer (score 10):

In M10.1+ you can use [`StringRiffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle):

```
StringRiffle[
    {"hi","how","are","you"},
    " "
] //InputForm
```

> "hi how are you"

Answer (score 3):

The `Map` function will "do the same thing" to every element in a list. So we use that to `StringJoin` a space onto the end of every word in your list, except the last word. And then we Use `StringJoin` on that plus the last word in your list to put all those together into a single string.  So

```
list = {"hi", "how", "are", "you"};
StringJoin[Map[StringJoin[#, " "]&, Most[list]], Last[list]]
```

which gives you the string "hi how are you"